# MLB: Home Run + Stolen Base in back to back games

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

On September 6, 2016 Jose Reyes hit a home run and stole a base in the same game.  The next day (September 7, 2016) he repeated the feat.

How many times has this been accomplished in the past, by what players?

Comment: A little different than your question, but here's a cool little quiz from Sporcle: http://m.sporcle.com/games/ileggin/mlb-most-games-with-hr-and-sb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 1913, this has happened 132 times according to Baseball Reference.

From 2006 to 2016, this has happened [17 times](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=2006&max_year_game=2016&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1). The criteria I used was "**Longest Streak with HR>=1, SB>=1 From 2006 to 2016.**"

Because I do not have a subscription to Baseball Reference, only 8 names came up on this list. This list is incomplete.

- 2006 - Ichiro Suzuki
- 2006 - Alfonso Soriano
- 2007 - Alex Rios
- 2007 - Rickie Weeks
- 2008 - Hanley Ramirez
- 2008 - Milton Bradley
- 2009 - Mark Reynolds
- 2010 - Ryan Braun
- more...

For previous years:

[17 times between 2000-2005](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#showform&gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=2000&max_year_game=2005&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1). (There was a player with back-to-back-to-back games with a home run and stolen base during this time).

[18 times between 1993-1999](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1993&max_year_game=1999&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

[15 times between 1987-1992](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1987&max_year_game=1992&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

[19 times between 1980-1986](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1980&max_year_game=1986&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

[18 times between 1970-1979](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1970&max_year_game=1979&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

[14 times between 1950-1969](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1950&max_year_game=1969&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

[Twice between 1930-1949](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1930&max_year_game=1949&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

[12 times between 1913-1929](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streak_finder.cgi?year=0&n1=&id=&type=b#gotresults&as=result_batter&offset=0&suffix=&min_year_game=1913&max_year_game=1929&series=any&series_game=any&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&bats=any&throws=any&HV=any&game_site=&pos_1=1&pos_2=1&pos_3=1&pos_4=1&pos_5=1&pos_6=1&pos_7=1&pos_8=1&pos_9=1&pos_10=1&pos_11=1&pos_12=1&exactness=any&GS=anyGS&lineup_position=&c4criteria=HR&c4gtlt=gt&c4val=1&c5criteria=SB&c5gtlt=gt&c5val=1&c6criteria=&c6gtlt=eq&c6val=0&playerapp=oneab&c1criteria=&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=0&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&location=pob&locationMatch=is&pob=&pod=&pcanada=&pusa=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1&z=1).

Comment: Thanks!  Trying to search on there without paying, it looks like someone might have done it 3 games in a row after 1995, but the site is only displaying the 10th ranked and above, not the top ranked which appears to be a '3'.  I thought it would be a more unusual feat but apparently it happens on average more than once per season.